# How do I render component based on selection from dropdown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm unable to reference the dropdown option created in the function **displayWarehouse()**  because it's generated from the database. The aim is to have the list of warehouses in a dropdown, then display another component based on warehouse selection but I keep getting the error

> cannot read property of undefined

For some reason I'm unable to access the individual options in the dropdown.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { option: 'Parchment House' };

    this.handlePick = this.handlePick.bind(this);
    // this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this)

}
displayWarehouse() {
    return (
        <select id="opt" onChange={this.handlePick} value={this.state.option}>
            {this.props.data.Warehouse.map((warehousename) => {
                return <option key={warehousename.warehouseID}>{warehousename.name}</option>;
            })}
        </select>
    );
}

displayBooks(num) {
    // console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('use').item(0).name)
    return this.props.data.Warehouse[num].books.map((titles) => {
        return (
            <div key={titles.bookID}>
                <li>
                    {titles.title} {titles.stock.balance}
                </li>
            </div>
        );
    });
}

handlePick(e) {
    console.log(this.state.option);
    this.setState({ option: e.target.value });
    // console.log(this.state.option);
}

componentDidMount() {
    // e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.option) {
        return <div>{this.displayBooks(1)}</div>;
    }

    return <div>{this.displayBooks(0)}</div>;
}

render() {
    if (this.props.data.loading) {
        return <div>loading...</div>;
    }

        <div className="zero" style={{ height: '100%' }}>
            <div className="titlebar">
            <label>Select Option</label>
            {this.displayWarehouse()}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}


export default graphql(fetchbooks)(Booklist);
```

Comment: What is the exact text of error?

Comment: Can you share more details on the `props` you are passing? I suspect the prop validation is missing and you are trying to parse an invalid Object. i.e. `this.props.data.Warehouse[num]` might be empty

Comment: Hmm maybe `this.displayWarehouse()` is expecting to get 1 argument but in the render you do not send any arguments ? so num is undefined ?